# Unmet dependencies don't let me install any applications

Tags: 20.04, dependencies

This red icon showed up after installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my Nvidia GPU desktop; I can't figure out how to solve this problem. It seems to be a notification thing. Here is the icon:

[image: red mark]

I think it has unmet dependencies.
I tried to run `sudo apt upgrade`, I got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-oem-20.04b : Depends: linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run `sudo apt autoremove`, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-oem-20.04b : Depends: linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried running `sudo apt-get -f install` and the issue still isn't solved, the following is the output of that command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10 linux-headers-5.10.0-1044-oem linux-headers-oem-20.04 linux-image-oem-20.04 linux-modules-5.10.0-1044-oem linux-oem-5.10-headers-5.10.0-1044
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-oem-5.10-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 338 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,693 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 341450 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem (5.10.0-1049.51) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-1049-oem.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

This is the output:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-oem-20.04b:
 linux-image-oem-20.04b depends on linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem; however:
  Package linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-oem-20.04b (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-oem-20.04b:
 linux-oem-20.04b depends on linux-image-oem-20.04b (= 5.10.0.1049.51); however:
  Package linux-image-oem-20.04b is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-oem-20.04b (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-oem-20.04:
 linux-image-oem-20.04 depends on linux-image-oem-20.04b; however:
  Package linux-image-oem-20.04b is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-oem-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-oem-20.04:
 linux-oem-20.04 depends on linux-oem-20.04b; however:
  Package linux-oem-20.04b is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-oem-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-oem-20.04b
 linux-oem-20.04b
 linux-image-oem-20.04
 linux-oem-20.04
```

Could someone please tell me how can I fix this?

Edited: this the out put of ubuntu verification `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Why are you using an OEM kernel? What's special about your hardware?

Comment: I have Nvidia gpu computer, GeForce RTX 2060. What OEM kernel means? It is a dual  boot Windows and Linux, also more than one user can login to the computer.

Comment: antivirus software on your system?